# s3 bucket syncing is running really slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, aws-cli

I am relatively new with AWS CLI. My S3 bucket syncing is running really slow between two S3 bucket, because I am running the command outside of Amazon (on prem server).

-Does it really slow down the S3 sync if I do it this way instead of running the command on one of the EC2 instance?

-I just need to clear my concept here. I was assuming if I were to sync between two S3 bucket, it should not really copy the content from one S3 to my on-prem server and then to another S3 bucket? It should just point the data of one S3 bucket to another?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command, then it sends a `copy` API request to Amazon S3. Amazon S3 will copy the objects directly between buckets (and even between regions) without the objects being downloaded to your computer.

It doesn't matter from where you run the `aws s3 sync` command — it will always copy the data just as fast, regardless of your network connection.

Comment: I see some other posts in stackoverflow which says running the aws-cli from one of the EC2 instance in the aws will have better results and low latency and marked as right answer. I just couldn't agree with that concept so I decided to ask.

Comment: An EC2 instance in the same region will send the API request with lower latency, but the copy will not be affected. A multi-part copy will involve more API requests, but it will be negligible compared to the amount of data actually copied.

Comment: Note that, even if the sync works directly, there could be another factors in the network that delay the API request. For example bad configurations of the IPv6 network path. In those case you can use the dual-stack endpoints of S3.